# CSS scollbar visibility

Tags: html, css

I want to add these rules in my css

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

But I want the scrollbar on the y-axis to be visible but should be dissabled.How can this be done?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want that?

Comment: Very vague question. Should it only be disabled when not needed, or every overflow should simply be gotten rid of? Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ametren : because I will be changing overflow-y:scroll; later and I dont want that change in width of the window due to that.

Comment: @DevashishDixit The width of the window is dynamic anyways, because the user can always resize the browser.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: I am just trying to get rid of that slight change in width that happens due to appearance of scrollbar when overflow-y:scroll; property is added to the body element.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: Yes I know, but most of us dont keep resizing our windows. Only we do this to check our websites.

Comment: You could add padding there equal to the width of the scrollbar, I believe the default is 17px.  Make sure you comment your CSS there to let future you know why you've done this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Even simpler without a container div.
Try this:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then, if you want the scrollbar enabled, remove `overflow: hidden;` from the body.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SKxhP/1/

Comment: Remove `overflow: hidden` from `#content` with Javascript if you need scrollbars again.

Answer (score 0):

Set your html height to 101%, this will cause the scrollbar to always show, thus preventing your content from jumping when the scrollbar would normally appear.

```
  html{

    height: 101%;

  }
```

See here: http://jsbin.com/ixuhoj/edit

Please correct me if I misinterpreted what you needed.